# IntelliJ IDEA does not show modifications to .idea directory in multi-repository (maven) project

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-repository, multi-module project like this:

```
─■ root <-- I have instructed IntelliJ IDEA to open this as a "project"
 ├─■ repository1
 │ ├─■ .git
 │ ├─■ .gitignore
 │ ├─■ pom.xml
 │ └─■ etc...
 ├─■ repository2
 │ ├─■ .git
 │ ├─■ .gitignore
 │ ├─■ pom.xml
 │ └─■ etc...
 └─■ .idea (also a repository)
   ├─■ .git
   ├─■ .gitignore
   ├─■ workspace.xml
   └─■ etc...
```

As you can see, there is no single root pom.xml, because each repository is meant to be independent of the others<sup>1</sup>. Instead, the project directory contains nothing but a sub-directory for each repository, and each repository has its own .git directory, its own root pom.xml file, and its own hierarchy of child poms.

When I instruct IntelliJ IDEA to open the root directory as a project, it finds each pom.xml file in each subdirectory, and from them it understands the entire project structure correctly. In doing so, it creates an .idea directory under the root directory of the project. So, I created one more git repository for the .idea directory, and I added a .gitignore file.

I can use TortoiseGit to work with the .idea directory, but I have so far been completely unsuccessful in convincing IntelliJ IDEA to show modifications to the .idea directory in the "Commit" tab. If I go to "git -> manage remotes..." the list (which is populated by IntelliJ IDEA and I am not allowed to add/remove entries) contains each of my code repositories but not the .idea repository.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to convince IntelliJ IDEA to show changes to the .idea directory in the "Commit" tab?

UPDATE:

After come unknown fiddling with the project, (probably after manually committing from TortoiseGit,) the .idea directory magically started appearing in the Intellij IDEA "Project" view; however:

- when I change a file in the .idea directory it is not colored to show that it has been modified;
- the file does not appear in the "Commit" view;
- the .idea repository still does not show in "git remotes".

---

<sup>1</sup> When someone checks out one of these repositories, I do not want them to have to cope with a missing parent pom.xml. However, some of the repositories depend on artifacts of others, so it still makes sense to have them all in one IntelliJ IDEA project, so that I can refactor them together.

Comment: Are you sure you want to ? `.idea` is pretty much the first thing to add to just about any `.gitignore` .

Comment: @Chai I know this is a popular choice, but actually, there are many files in the `.idea` directory that are very well worth version-controlling. If you search for this, you will find recommendations as to which files from **_within_** the `.idea` directory to add to `.gitignore`, the rest all being fair game for git.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I personally do not use intellij. I guess I just have not come across any project that had anything in that directory in git, since it is all generated anyway. Other prople would still have to check out each repo right? And then open up the "root" folder. So would that not just as easily generate the whole ..idea` for them as well ? Also (let me know if I miss the mark here:) is it not true that you would force your colleagues to always checkout out ALL the repos, since otherwise the administration in `.idea` complains ? If so, then maybe it is just easier to make it a monorepo

Comment: @Chai your understanding of how it all works is good. Versioning the .idea directory is useful for my purposes because in there IntelliJ IDEA stores many things that I have painstakingly defined, like scopes, and copyright templates (which depend on scopes) and even run configurations, which are all a pain to re-create when cloning from scratch.

Comment: @MikeNakis _shared_ run configurations go elsewhere. You  may want to consider that

Comment: I'm not an IntelliJ Idea user, so this is just a very remote suggestion : your IDE probably has settings that instruct it to *not* treat `.idea/` as a subpoject. Pehaps you can try to open that directory as a separate project in another ItelliJ Idea instance ? or run some "create project" action in that directory that will create a structure so that it gets detected as a project  (e.g : have you tried placing a phony `pom.xml` in it) ?

Comment: @LeGEC you are a genius! I added a phony pom.xml with just `<project>` and `<groupId>` and IntelliJ IDEA has now started treating the `.idea` directory as a directory under version control!  Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Probably all it takes is a line in `.idea/vcs.xml` that says `<mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea" vcs="Git" />` but the phony pom.xml file is worth keeping around in case I need to re-create the entire project after a fresh checkout.